# input type hidden attribute value missing when I inspect with Fiddler

Tags: input, httpclient, hidden

For the same request, the attrib `value` of tag `input type=hidden` is not displayed on the content (raw text) of the response using Fiddler and VStudio debugger. But when I inspect the code with Chrome it is displayed. Why does this happen?  See these snapshots:

Element inspect from google

[image: Element inspect from google]

Inspector response content from Fiddler4

[image: Inspector response content from Fiddler4]

I'm a beginner in HTTP and HTML.

Comment: Fiddler shows the raw HTML exactly as it is transmitted from the webserver.  So either the webserver is sending different HTML when Fiddler is debugging it, or maybe the HTML contains client-side scripting that is manipulating the HTML content after it is loaded into a browser.  Chrome shows you the current HTML content as it appears within the parsed DOM tree, not the original HTML as it was received from the webserver. Scripting can manipulate the DOM. If you want someone to help you figure this out, it would help if you provide a URL that they can see the HTML in action for themselves.

Comment: Oh thanks for the information. Taking your answer, I have examined the  script section and could I confirm what you mention, there is a dynamic script that sets the value for that input tag.
thank you @RemyLebeau & SO !